# appending array in php / CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am try to append my data array in if conditions. I am using `array_push` function to do it Its first time I am using this function for appending array. I am using conditions so that if user has added the value in the form it would update the field otherwise It would not effect the field. The problem is its not updating the database and its unable to set the fields as it shows Unknown Unknown column '0' in 'field list'

```
$fid = 2;
$password = "test_pass";
$title = "new title of folder";
$f_access = 1;
$newName = TRUE;

$data = array(
              'name' => $title,
              'access_type' => $f_access
              );

if($newName)
{
    $data2 = "'icon' => $newName";
    array_push($data, $data2);
}

if($password)
{
    $data3 =   "'password' => $password";
    array_push($data, $data3);
}

$this->db->where('id', $fid);
$this->db->update('folders', $data);
```

Comment: You want $data['icon'] = $newName; instead of push for this

Comment: stock values in an new array for transition and use `array_merge` to preserve precedent indexes

Comment: Please read up on PHP [arrays](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert new data into a key => value array you have to use the form:

```
 $arr['key'] = value;
```

as

```
 $data['password'] = $password;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
          'name' => $title,
          'access_type' => $f_access
          );

if(!empty($newName))
    $data['icon'] = $newName;

if(!empty($password))
    $data['password'] = $password;
```

This way you can easily push new items in the array.